# How to properly set pinia state from Nuxt Page

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3, pinia, nuxt3

In my pet project, I have a list of shops and a current active one defined in Pinia store

```
export const useShopStore = defineStore('shop', {
    state: () => {
        return {
            currentShop: null as Shop | null,
            shops: [] as Shop[],
        }
    },
    actions: {
        setCurrentShop: function (shop: Shop) {
            this.currentShop = shop;
        },
        // ...
    }
})
```

On index.vue page I have v-select to choose active store

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
import { mapWritableState } from 'pinia'
import { useShopStore } from '@/stores/shop'
import { onMounted } from 'vue'
import Shop from "models/Shop";

const shopStore = useShopStore();
shopStore.fetchShops(); // fetch shops from api
let { shops, currentShop } = storeToRefs(shopStore)

let selectedStoreId = ref(null);
const selectedStore = computed(() => shops.value.find(shop => shop.id === selectedStoreId.value));

watch(selectedStoreId, (newStoreIndex) => {
    let  shop:Shop = shops.value.find(shop => shop.id === newStoreIndex) as Shop 
    shopStore.setCurrentShop(shop)
}),

// add on mount hook to set selected store in v-select component
onMounted(() => {
    if (currentShop.value) {
        selectedStoreId.value = currentShop.value.id
    }
})

</script>
<template>
    <NuxtLayout>
        <v-container fluid>
            <p v-if="currentShop"> currentShop {{ currentShop.name }}</p>
            <p v-else>Shop not selected</p>
            
            <v-select label="Select Store" 
                      :items="shops" 
                      item-title="name" 
                      item-value="id" v-model="selectedStoreId">
                      </v-select>
        </v-container>
    </NuxtLayout>
</template>
```

As you can notice I set `currentShop` in pinia store by calling action `shopStore.setCurrentShop(shop)` whin `watch ()`.

1. Is there way to simply assign pinia's state `currentShop` to selected in `v-select`?
2. Is it possible to use pinia's state `currentShop` as `v-model` within v-select and avoid these tricks with `watch` and `computed selectedStore`?